# Angular2 - update select template from component

Tags: javascript, angular, model, components

I have a select element in my component template that is hooked up a selectedEmp model.I want to be able to update the selectedEmp in the component and have the correct value show in the select element. My current setup is not letting this happen. Instead the select value does not display the selectedEmp. I console logged the selectedEmp, and its value is changing. I think this is because the option element is never set to any value when i do it via the component. Does anyone know a way to do this.

Component.html

```
        <select name="sel1" class="form-control" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmp">
            <option [value]="employee" *ngFor="let employee of employees">
                {{employee}}
            </option>
        </select>
```

Component.ts

```
employees:Array<string> = ["Andrew","Allen","Kevin","Phil"]; 
visable:boolean = false; 
selectedEmp:any = null; 
constructor(){}
// Selection change 
onChange(value:any):void {
    console.log(value);
}
updateModel(){
    this.selectedEmp = "Allen"
}
```

Comment: Not really understanding the problem, could you describe it a bit further? And when is `updateModel` called? And exactly where is the model not updating, in template?

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear from your question but I did see one error on your `(ngModelChange)` event binding, since the items are strings, `$event.target.value fails` try `(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"`.

But that was only for console anyway, so removing it leaves:

```
<button type="button" (click)="updateModel()">Select Allen</button>

<select name="sel1" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmp">
        <option [value]="employee" *ngFor="let employee of employees">
            {{employee}}
        </option>
</select>
```